# Enabling http/2 in Apache 2.4 does not work

Tags: apache, ssl, http2

We are trying to enable http/2 on Apache 2.4, but with no success.
The server OS is FreeBSD 11.2, and the OpenSSL version is 1.0.2o.

We have a real and valid SSL Certificate with the rating A+ at Qualys SSL Server Test.

No errors in log files, the server restarts without no problems or errors. Access website with https:// works, but browser always downgrades to http/1.1.

We have this in our virtual section:

```
<Directory />
    Require         all granted
    AllowOverride   All
    SSLOptions      +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions      +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

H2Direct on
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

Options                    None
SSLEngine                  On
SSLHonorCipherOrder        On
SSLSessionTickets          Off
SSLCompression             Off
SSLCipherSuite             "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
SSLProtocol                All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

SSLCertificateFile          "/usr/local/www/apache24/certs/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile       "/usr/local/www/apache24/certs/server.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile     "/usr/local/www/apache24/certs/intermediate.crt"

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

---UPDATE---

```
root@srv04:/usr/home/user # httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.35 (FreeBSD)
Server built:   unknown
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:82
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.3, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.6.3, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
threaded:     no
forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses disabled)
-D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/bin/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="/var/run/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="/var/log/httpd-error.log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="etc/apache24/mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="etc/apache24/httpd.conf"
```

---ALPN FROM QUALSYS---

```
ALPN    Yes   http/1.1
```

---CHROME---

```
Chrome 49 / XP SP3 RSA 2048 (SHA256) TLS 1.2 > http/1.1     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ECDH secp256r1  FS
Chrome 69 / Win 7 R RSA 2048 (SHA256) TLS 1.2 > http/1.1    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ECDH secp256r1  FS
Chrome 70 / Win 10 RSA 2048 (SHA256) TLS 1.2 > http/1.1     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ECDH secp256r1  FS
```

Comment: Does SSLServerTest show you can use h2 for Chrome for example? Are you using prefork MPM? What version of Apache are you using? Do you have any antivirus software with SSL scanning software or proxies which might be downgrading the connection?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Server version: Apache/2.4.35 (FreeBSD), Compiled in modules:  core.c, mod_so.c,  http_core.c. No proxies or firewalls, other websites we access indicates active http2 (Chrome & Firefox HTTP/2 addons).

Comment: Does SSLLabs say it's h2 or not for Chrome for example? Also does it show ALPN support? And which MPM are you running (run `httpd -V` to see this)?

Comment: Thanks again, updating my question.

Comment: Depending on the way you test it, it could be that [antivirus is intercepting HTTPS requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/752767/trying-to-setup-http2-on-apache) and that prevents HTTP/2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache does not support HTTP/2 with prefork MPM. [This was added in 2.4.27](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4):

> *) COMPATIBILITY: mod_http2: Disable and give warning when using Prefork.
>        The server will continue to run, but HTTP/2 will no longer be negotiated.
>        [Stefan Eissing]

The Prefork MPM is [basically incompatible with the way HTTP/2 is implemented](https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/142). There should be a warning in your error logs after restart telling you this.

Prefork is also a very old MPM that is slow, so those sites that want HTTP/2 probably shouldn't be using it anyway. It should only really be used if you are running non-threadsafe PHP applications (threadsafe ones should move to Event MPM and [php-fm](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/php) (which is basically how Nginx runs as it does not offer a prefork equivalent). Unfortunately it is also the default on many Apache installs (just i case people use thread-unsafe PHP applications?), and often you cannot change it without downloading and recompiling it.

More info on MPMs here: https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use

Comment: Thank you! Going to reconfigure Apache for Event MPM, and then reinstall it. Seems to be loading as a module in httpd.conf. PHP-FM was already installed with PHP5.6, I have activated it, and started it. Keep your fingers crossed now!

Comment: Well while on the upgrade path, you might wanna reconsider that PHP version too: https://www.zdnet.com/article/around-62-of-all-internet-sites-will-run-an-unsupported-php-version-in-10-weeks/