# http/2 on Apache and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lets-encrypt, http2, apache2.4

I am running a Wordpress instance on Ubuntu 16.04, Apache/2.4.41, Let's encrypt for HTTPS and I want to enable http/2. Therefore successfully installed http2 and activated it by `sudo a2enmod http2`. This worked fine. Afterwards I modified the apache2.conf, inserted `Protocols h2 http/1.1` and restarted apache again. However there was no change. So I updated the configuration in sites-available inserting the Protocols tag for the specific site and restarted apache again. No success again. What else can I do to enable http/2?

Comment: What shows in error logs once you restart Apache?

Comment: Looking at the error log it says something like: ```The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.```

Comment: Well there’s your reason. Switch to event mpm and HTTP/2 will start working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling http/2 in Apache 2.4 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714001/enabling-http-2-in-apache-2-4-does-not-work)